# Adding an interior wall to make additional bedroom

Tags: walls, framing, carpet, interior, addition

I’m wanting to add an interior (non load bearing) wall to close off an open space in my house. I would also be adding a door, and a closet and door on the other side. This is a second floor area and it is carpeted. I’m trying to find good guidance on how to deal with the carpet, and I just can’t find it.

How do I deal with the carpet? Can I staple it and cut only where I will be building? I understand that building on top of the carpet is a quick workaround, but I want to do this right. Should I just rip up all the carpet and start fresh (not desired)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would remove the carpet where the wall is going to be.  If you measure right, can probably lay the bottom plate on the carpet and use it as a straight edge to cut carpet.  Make sure of your measurements before cutting.  A bedroom  requires a second egress/way of getting out(a big enough window).

Comment: @crip659 Write that up as an answer.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with the carpet to hold it in place after I cut it? That’s what I really need to know. I’ve never stretched carpet before. Can I just throw staples down? Egress is not an issue, this area has 2 windows on the wall opposite of where I’m building.

Comment: I would cut it in the middle of where the wall is going and fold/tack it back. After the wall is finished install the tack strip and put in place. You should have to trim a bit off of each side. I do not know if this is the approved method but it worked for me.